# Is it possible to add or replace a language in a web stack? (Important)

Tags: java, php, web-applications, wamp, lamp

I am new to programming and I was reading up on "web development," and "web stacks." I've Googled this question and there were no hits, so I've decided to come here and ask. Here are my questions:

Is it possible to replace a language in a web stack? For example, I wanted to use LAMP, but I decided to use Java as the language instead of PHP.

If I can't replace a language, is it possible to add another language in also? For example, I used LAMP, and added Java.

Please respond to your best abilities and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A Web development stack is where you have certain languages and/or technologies that are sufficient to work together to build a website. For example,

`LAMP stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP`
`WAMP stands for Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP`

Now these can be considered as minimal requirements to build a dynamic website.
To change any of them with another language/technology largely depends on whether it is possible or not. For Java web development, you have to read on JSP, and what technologies(system/server/database) goes with it. Swapping languages/technologies becomes more possible if you use more commonly used languages/technologies for web development, like RubyOnRails or Python.

Personally, I would recommend you to go for popular web stacks for the sheer amount of resource you can find. Any problems you encounter, chances are another person also encountered it and found a solution right here on stackoverflow.